# File download - Out Of Memory(OOM)

Tags: android, file, out-of-memory, large-files

I'm having some troubles with downloading files on some devices, I get OOM error. Here is the code that I used to download large files:

```
/**
 * The size of the chunks that an file is split when writing to server.<br />
 * 1024 * 1024 -> 1mb
 */
private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

File output = new File(sdCardPath, fileName);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
try {
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

int offset = 0;

// compute the number of chunks of 1 mb for downloading the file
// by parts
int parts = tmpFileSize / CHUNK_SIZE;
ByteString readingfile = null;
long progressUpdate = 0;

for (int partsCounter = 0; partsCounter < parts + 1; partsCounter++) {
    try {
        readingfile = serviceApi
                .readFile(
                        session,
                        filehandle, offset, CHUNK_SIZE);

        byte[] bytesRead = readingfile.toByteArray();
        int numberOfBytesReaded = bytesRead.length;
        offset = offset + numberOfBytesReaded;
        progress.publish(""
                + (int) ((progressUpdate * 100) / tmpFileSize));
        progressUpdate += numberOfBytesReaded;
        fileOutputStream.write(bytesRead, 0,
                numberOfBytesReaded);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

try {
    if (null != fileOutputStream) {
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can someone let me know if I'm doing something wrong here ? Thank you.

---

Solution based on @Ari answer I've updated the code. Now it is optimized to use only 1mb (I don't know if it is the best way to split the process in chunks but it seems to be improved now and it doesn't give OOM). I will try and further optimize it by detecting how much heap memory I can use, but I'm not sure I can achieve this. Until than this seems to be the best option.
Thank you again @Ari.

Comment: Images you downloading?

Comment: It could be any type of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many buffers you don't need.

1. `byte[] br = readingfile.toByteArray();` you are using to get `numberOfBytesReaded`.
2. Then you are getting array again: `inputStream = ... readingfile.toByteArray());`
   And copy it to third buffer
3. `byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];`.

Try to use just one for all of these operations.

General advice is to set pointers of objects (and arrays) to `NULL` when you don't need them anymore.

I would use code like this:

```
for (int partsCounter = 0; partsCounter < parts + 1; partsCounter++) {
    readingfile = serviceApi.readFile(session, filehandle, offset,
            (int) bufferSize);
    byte[] br = readingfile.toByteArray();
    int numberOfBytesReaded = br.length;
    offset = offset + numberOfBytesReaded;

    try {
            progress.publish(""
                    + (int) ((progressUpdate * 100) / tmpFileSize));
            progressUpdate += numberOfBytesReaded;
            fileOutputStream.write(br, 0, numberOfBytesReaded);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give me OOM faster ? Or you think that because I'm already splitting the file in chunks the fileOutputStream will be overridden for each iteration ?

Comment: @IonutNegru I updated code. I think, your code would use 4MB of memory (2 buffers, 1 input stream and 1 output). Mine needs only 1MB + 128KB.

Comment: @IonutNegru I think `fileOutputStream` doesn't need its own memory, so your code was using 3MB, mine 1MB.

Comment: This is a horrible way to do things. If you don't need the byte data, then never read it fully into memory. Instead open an input and output stream and copy it (for example) 8kb at a time (Apache commons-io project has a ready made tool for this). The ByteStream.toByteArray() creates a completely useless copy of the whole file data and the original copy is discarded (when the loop ends). That readFile(...) method just isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: The readFile method is an custom method that reads a file(in chunks or the entire file) through an API service from the server and will return how many bytes were read at one time.
I can't change that method, it will affect too many services that use it.

Comment: @Torben `readFile` is method from Ionut Negur API. You can't create Stream through Internet. Here we are downloading 1MB at a time. It is still big amount of data, but it is Ionut's decision. I just reduce needed memory from `3*bufferSize` to `1*bufferSize`.

Comment: Exactly @Ari, but why you think 1mb is big ? Do you think I should split it in smaller chunks ? For example what chunk size you think would be best to use ?

Comment: @IonutNegru If users don't need these files as soon as possible and you want to support old android devices I would use 32kB - 256kB chunks.

Comment: The file is downloaded to be opened on the device. An window indicating the progress is shown while doing this(upon canceling the dialog the task is also canceled). So the faster the process, the better.
By old android devices, what you mean ? I'm targeting devices with API > 8, do you know if older versions have a limit for this ?

Comment: @IonutNegru bigger chunks means: probably faster download, higher risk of connection error (especially for slow connection; sending one chunk takes more time), less devices supported. Test  different chunk sizes and pick best for you, but I wouldn't use chunks bigger than 256kB

Comment: @Ari It's actually still 2*bufferSize. But yeah, it's about as good as you can get with the API we know about.